# UIViewcontroller instance getting null & not invoking the file for view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

I am generating a PDF File and with the help of UIViewcontroller i invoke the PDF file for viewing but for some unknown reason my UIViewcontroller is getting null.

```
    string path = 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    string filePath = Path.Combine(path,filename);

    //Create a file and write the stream into it.
    FileStream fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create);
    stream.Position = 0;
    stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    fileStream.Flush();
    fileStream.Close();

    //Invoke the saved document for viewing
    UIViewController currentController = 
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
    while (currentController.PresentedViewController != null)
        currentController = currentController.PresentedViewController;
    UIView currentView = currentController.View;

    QLPreviewController qlPreview = new QLPreviewController();
    QLPreviewItem item = new QLPreviewItemBundle(filename, filePath);
    qlPreview.DataSource = new PreviewControllerDS(item);

    currentController.PresentViewController(qlPreview, true, null);
```

This is My AppDelegate.cs file please check this

```
 [Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : 
global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{



    //
    // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
    // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
    // visible.
    //
    // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
    //
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        //CarouselViewRenderer.Init();

        FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.CachedImageRenderer.Init();

        LoadApplication(new App());
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarHidden = true;


        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the rootviewcontroller in AppDelegate.cs?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT check my Questions again i have edited the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the following code (I implement it by DependencyService)

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(OpenPdfFile))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class OpenPdfFile : IGetRootViewController
    {


        public void GetRootViewController()
        {


            string path  = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            string filePath = Path.Combine(path,filename);

            //Create a file and write the stream into it.
            FileStream fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            stream.Position = 0;
            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Flush();
            fileStream.Close();

            var previewController = new QLPreviewController();
            previewController.DataSource = new QuickLookSource("file://"+filePath);

            UIViewController currentController =
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
            while (currentController.PresentedViewController != null)
                currentController = currentController.PresentedViewController;

            currentController.PresentViewController(previewController,true,null);
        }




    }


    public class QuickLookSource : QLPreviewControllerDataSource
    {
        string filePath;

        public QuickLookSource(string path)
        {
            filePath = path;
        }

        public override nint PreviewItemCount(QLPreviewController controller)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public override IQLPreviewItem GetPreviewItem(QLPreviewController controller, nint index)
        {
            return new PreviewItem(filePath);
        }
    }

    public class PreviewItem : QLPreviewItem
    {
        NSUrl fileUrl;

        public override NSUrl ItemUrl => fileUrl;
        public override string ItemTitle => fileUrl.LastPathComponent;

        public PreviewItem(string url)
        {
            fileUrl = new NSUrl(url,true);
        }
    }


}
```

**Note**: Check the filepath of your pdf if it is right.

Comment: its throwing an exception like this " you are calling a uikit method that can only be invoked from the ui thread"

Comment: The same peace   of code is also executing on other button but that button just view my pdf but here its not working but this code first write the file and then viewing up.

Comment: Thanks we got our solution.The problem was in our code.